# What are the disadvantages of a Top-up undergraduate degree

Tags: masters, united-kingdom

Can I use a top-up degree to apply for a Master's program?
I enrolled in a Top-up degree program after graduating with a Third class degree in Bachelor of Science in Physics. I am wondering if I can apply for a Master's degree program with a transcript of the Top-up degree and the Bachelor of Science degree.

Comment: What is a top-up degree programm: https://www.ukstudyonline.com/what-is-a-top-up-degree/ (hopefully all the informations contained there are true).
It looks like it is a very specific program to very specific situations in the UK. How many open positions descriptions are asking for a HND degree? for a full b degree?

Comment: Can you explain to non-native English speakers what is a top-up degree? Is it a specifically American concept?

Comment: @Miguel - it is not an American thing. Looks UK specific?

Comment: No. It does not. It results in disorientation because a particular University outside of the Russian Federation accepts the 120ECTS credits units earned in the TopUp degree for a Master's degree program.
Do I understand that acceptance of the TopUp degree is University specific?

Comment: I think you will find most western universities do not understand the meaning of different Russian degrees.

Comment: If you want to find out if your degree will help you reach your goal, the best (but still imperfect) source of information is other people who got that degree.

Answer (score 0):

Universities have some freedom in defining (and waiving) admission criteria.

I am sure that you will get a better guidance by contacting the admission office of the universities you are interested, rather than asking strangers on the internet :) .

Said this, you can always do this survey yourself and afterwards write here the answer to your own question, so you will help all the people that may have the same problem and they may find the solution here.

Comment: I am wondering why a University in Russia is not considering my application for a Master's program because I accomplished the top-up degree in six semesters.

Comment: @PoppaDynasty only that university can answer you.

Comment: This does not answer the question, does it?